# JavaScript : when B inherits from A, callbacks in A cannot see B

Tags: javascript, callback, scope, this

Cannot figure out how to get access to the "extended" properties of a child object from a callback in the parent. My two attempts are below. I would like for the function "say_something" to alert "say hi", where "hi" comes from the child. Instead, it says "say undefined".

Attempt 1 : I create an object "a", then create a new object "b" that derives from it. But a callback in "a" (here from a setTimeout) won't have access to the correct "this".

```
var a = {};
a.say_something = function () { setTimeout( function () { alert( "say " + this.text ); }, 0 ); };

var b = Object.create( a );
b.text = "hi";

b.say_something(); // alerts "say undefined"
```

Attempt 2 : Common wisdom says re-arrange to allow for a "that" variable which can be accessed in the callback. But unlike "this", "that" cannot access properties from "b" :

```
var a = ( function () {
    var that = {};
    that.say_something = function () { setTimeout( function () { alert( "say " + that.text ); }, 0 ); };
    return that;
}() );

var b = ( function () {
    var that = Object.create( a );
    that.text = "hi";
    return that;
}() );

b.say_something(); // alerts "say undefined"
```

PS, I use Douglas Crockford's Object.create function instead of the (confusing to me) new(). It is copied here:

```
if ( typeof Object.create !== "function" ) {
    Object.create = function ( o ) {
        function F() {}
        F.prototype = o;
        return new F();
    };
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add

```
a.say_something();
```

to you first example it will also return `say undefined`.  The problem is that `setTimeout` does not execute the code it calls in the scope in which it is called.

We can solve this by either:

1. Hard-coding a reference to the existing object `alert('say ' + a.text);`
2. Using [`call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) and [`apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) to specify the context in which the function should execute.  (And [`bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) too -- for the newest platforms.)

Approach #2 is what you are looking for.

```
var a = {};
a.text = "hello!";
function say_something() {
    var that = this; // Save the reference to *this* this.
    setTimeout( function() { console.log.call(that, "say " + that.text ); }, 0 ); 
}
a.say_something = say_something;
a.say_something(); // say hello!

var b = ( function () {
    var that = Object.create( a );
    that.text = "hi there!";
    return that;
}() );

b.say_something(); // say hi there!
```

Comment: "Save the reference to *this* this" is what did it. Thanks! To get my "Attempt 2" code to work, I added a *second* "var that = this;" directly before the call to setTimeout, as you suggest. (It shadows/"overwrites" the first "var that = {};", which I continue to use elsewhere)

Answer (score 2):

In a setTimeout function, "this" always refers to the Window object.

What I usually do is something like (tested and works)

```
a.say_something = function () {
    var thisObj = this;
    setTimeout(function () { 
        alert( "say " + thisObj.text ); 
    }, 0 ); 
};
```

Comment: Does this address the parent-child problem at all?